# PCA generating less principal components than the number of original variables

Tags: r, pca

I've been applying PCA to some data sets and in all previous cases, the number of principal components generated by *prcomp()* was always equal to the number of original variables (*m*). However, I've stumbled upon this case where the number of PCs computed is less than *m*.

In this case, my data set has 40 variables (including the class label in the *m*-th column) and 36 observations. My code for applying PCA is:

```
data = read.csv("datasets/chemical/chocolate.csv", sep=",", dec=".")
m = length(data)
n = nrow(data)

pca = prcomp(data[,-m], scale=FALSE)
loadings = pca$rotation
scores = pca$x
```

But only 36 principal components were computed this time. So the loadings matrix returned by *pca$rotation* was 39x36.

Why does it happen? Why did *prcomp()* compute fewer principal components than the number of original variables in this particular case? Is this an issue with my code or with my data?

Comment: Please do not re-post your question: improve the original instead.

Comment: @whuber I tried to, but it has been blocked and I couldn't edit it.

Comment: I am very sorry about that, Camila.  This happened automatically because your original post arrived here *via* migration from another SE site, and I didn't catch it.  I believe I have now "unlocked" the post, which ought to enable you to modify it as you wish.  If you cannot, please flag the post for further moderator attention.